# Make an Update Required Dialog in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I pretty much want to make an update alert dialog in which you can't click out of it whenever there is an update file released into google play

Answer (score 0):

Use an alert dialogue, and set `dissmissable: false`.

Answer (score 0):

To check for whether there is an update on Google Play, you can create an API to check if the newest version is available.

For example if using Firestore, create a document with field `app_version_number`. Update this field whenever you push a new version to the Store. Within the app, fetch this data from Firestore then compare it with your current app version. If the version is differ, it will show a Dialog with the Update button to navigate to the Play Store.

For the non dismissible Dialog, There's a property called `barrierDismissible` which makes dialogs dismissible or not on external click.

```dart
showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: true, // Set this to true
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () => Future.value(false),
            child:AlertDialog(
            title: new Text("Alert Title"),
            content: new SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(),),
            actions: <Widget>[
              new FlatButton(
                child: new Text("Close"),
                onPressed: () {
                },
              ),
            ],
          )
        )
      },
    );
```